# calculate churn based on 21 days interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, git, dataframe

I worked on calculating churn using the mix of pandas dataframe of git logs and `git show` command for a particular commit to see where exactly the changes has been done based on loc. However, I could not able to calculate churn based on the days i.e. I mean calculate churn when an engineer rewrites or deletes their own code that is less than 3 weeks old.

This is how I have done for such dataframe for each commit based

git logs dataframe

```
        sha timestamp   date    author  message body    age insertion   deletion    filepath    churn   merges
1   1   cae635054   Sat Jun 26 14:51:23 2021 -0400  2021-06-26 18:51:23+00:00   Andrew Clark    `act`: Resolve to return value of scope function (#21759)   When migrating some internal tests I found it annoying that I couldn't  -24 days +12:21:32.839997                   
2   21  cae635054   Sat Jun 26 14:51:23 2021 -0400  2021-06-26 18:51:23+00:00   Andrew Clark    `act`: Resolve to return value of scope function (#21759)   When migrating some internal tests I found it annoying that I couldn't  -24 days +12:21:32.839997   31.0    0.0 packages/react-reconciler/src/__tests__/ReactIsomorphicAct-test.js  31.0    
3   22  cae635054   Sat Jun 26 14:51:23 2021 -0400  2021-06-26 18:51:23+00:00   Andrew Clark    `act`: Resolve to return value of scope function (#21759)   When migrating some internal tests I found it annoying that I couldn't  -24 days +12:21:32.839997   1.0 1.0 packages/react-test-renderer/src/ReactTestRenderer.js   0.0 
4   23  cae635054   Sat Jun 26 14:51:23 2021 -0400  2021-06-26 18:51:23+00:00   Andrew Clark    `act`: Resolve to return value of scope function (#21759)   When migrating some internal tests I found it annoying that I couldn't  -24 days +12:21:32.839997   24.0    14.0    packages/react/src/ReactAct.js  10.0    
5   25  e2453e200   Fri Jun 25 15:39:46 2021 -0400  2021-06-25 19:39:46+00:00   Andrew Clark    act: Add test for bypassing queueMicrotask (#21743) Test for fix added in #21740    -25 days +13:09:55.839997   50.0    0.0 packages/react-reconciler/src/__tests__/ReactIsomorphicAct-test.js  50.0    
6   27  73ffce1b6   Thu Jun 24 22:42:44 2021 -0400  2021-06-25 02:42:44+00:00   Brian Vaughn    DevTools: Update tests to fix warnings/errors (#21748)  Some new ones had slipped in (e.g. deprecated ReactDOM.render message from 18)  -26 days +20:12:53.839997   4.0 5.0 packages/react-devtools-shared/src/__tests__/FastRefreshDevToolsIntegration-test.js -1.0    
7   28  73ffce1b6   Thu Jun 24 22:42:44 2021 -0400  2021-06-25 02:42:44+00:00   Brian Vaughn    DevTools: Update tests to fix warnings/errors (#21748)  Some new ones had slipped in (e.g. deprecated ReactDOM.render message from 18)  -26 days +20:12:53.839997   4.0 4.0 packages/react-devtools-shared/src/__tests__/componentStacks-test.js    0.0 
8   29  73ffce1b6   Thu Jun 24 22:42:44 2021 -0400  2021-06-25 02:42:44+00:00   Brian Vaughn    DevTools: Update tests to fix warnings/errors (#21748)  Some new ones had slipped in (e.g. deprecated ReactDOM.render message from 18)  -26 days +20:12:53.839997   12.0    12.0    packages/react-devtools-shared/src/__tests__/console-test.js    0.0 
9   30  73ffce1b6   Thu Jun 24 22:42:44 2021 -0400  2021-06-25 02:42:44+00:00   Brian Vaughn    DevTools: Update tests to fix warnings/errors (#21748)  Some new ones had slipped in (e.g. deprecated ReactDOM.render message from 18)  -26 days +20:12:53.839997   7.0 6.0 packages/react-devtools-shared/src/__tests__/editing-test.js    1.0 
10  31  73ffce1b6   Thu Jun 24 22:42:44 2021 -0400  2021-06-25 02:42:44+00:00   Brian Vaughn    DevTools: Update tests to fix warnings/errors (#21748)  Some new ones had slipped in (e.g. deprecated ReactDOM.render message from 18)  -26 days +20:12:53.839997   47.0    42.0    packages/react-devtools-shared/src/__tests__/inspectedElement-test.js   5.0 
11  32  73ffce1b6   Thu Jun 24 22:42:44 2021 -0400  2021-06-25 02:42:44+00:00   Brian Vaughn    DevTools: Update tests to fix warnings/errors (#21748)  Some new ones had slipped in (e.g. deprecated ReactDOM.render message from 18)  -26 days +20:12:53.839997   7.0 6.0 packages/react-devtools-shared/src/__tests__/ownersListContext-test.js  1.0 
12  33  73ffce1b6   Thu Jun 24 22:42:44 2021 -0400  2021-06-25 02:42:44+00:00   Brian Vaughn    DevTools: Update tests to fix warnings/errors (#21748)  Some new ones had slipped in (e.g. deprecated ReactDOM.render message from 18)  -26 days +20:12:53.839997   22.0    21.0    packages/react-devtools-shared/src/__tests__/profilerContext-test.js    1.0
```

**churn calculation**

```
commits = df["sha"].unique().tolist()
for commit in commits:
    contribution, churn = await self.calculate_churn(commit)

async def calculate_churn(self, stream):
        PREVIOUS_BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath("")
        try:
            GIT_DIR = os.path.join(PREVIOUS_BASE_DIR, "app/git/react.git")
            os.chdir(GIT_DIR)
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            raise ValueError(e)
        cmd = f"git show --format= --unified=0 --no-prefix {stream}"
        cmds = [f"{cmd}"]
        results = get_proc_out(cmds)
        [files, contribution, churn] = get_loc(results)
        # need to circle back to previous path
        os.chdir(PREVIOUS_BASE_DIR)
        return contribution, churn


def is_new_file(result, file):
    # search for destination file (+++ ) and update file variable
    if result.startswith("+++"):
        return result[result.rfind(" ") + 1 :]
    else:
        return file


def is_loc_change(result, loc_changes):
    # search for loc changes (@@ ) and update loc_changes variable
    # @@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
    # @@ -l,s +l,s @@
    if result.startswith("@@"):
        # loc_change = result[2+1: ] -> -1,5 +1,4 @@
        loc_change = result[result.find(" ") + 1 :]
        # loc_change = loc_change[:9] -> -1,5 +1,4
        loc_change = loc_change[: loc_change.find(" @@")]
        return loc_change
    else:
        return loc_changes


def get_loc_change(loc_changes):
    # removals
    # -1,5 +1,4 = -1,5
    left = loc_changes[: loc_changes.find(" ")]
    left_dec = 0
    # 2
    if left.find(",") > 0:
        # 2
        comma = left.find(",")
        # 5
        left_dec = int(left[comma + 1 :])
        # 1
        left = int(left[1:comma])
    else:
        left = int(left[1:])
        left_dec = 1

    # additions
    # +1,4
    right = loc_changes[loc_changes.find(" ") + 1 :]
    right_dec = 0
    if right.find(",") > 0:
        comma = right.find(",")
        right_dec = int(right[comma + 1 :])
        right = int(right[1:comma])
    else:
        right = int(right[1:])
        right_dec = 1

    if left == right:
        return {left: (right_dec - left_dec)}
    else:
        return {left: left_dec, right: right_dec}


def get_loc(results):
    files = {}
    contribution = 0
    churn = 0
    file = ""
    loc_changes = ""
    for result in results:
        new_file = is_new_file(result, file)
        if file != new_file:
            file = new_file
            if file not in files:
                files[file] = {}
        else:
            new_loc_changes = is_loc_change(
                result, loc_changes
            )  # returns either empmty or -6 +6 or -13, 0 +14, 2 format
            if loc_changes != new_loc_changes:
                loc_changes = new_loc_changes
                locc = get_loc_change(loc_changes)  # {2: 0} or {8: 0, 9: 1}
                for loc in locc:
                    # files[file] = {2: 0, 8: 0, 9: 1}
                    #  print("loc", loc, files[file], locc[loc])
                    if loc in files[file]:
                        # change of lines triggered
                        files[file][loc] += locc[loc]
                        churn += abs(locc[loc])
                    else:
                        files[file][loc] = locc[loc]
                        contribution += abs(locc[loc])
            else:
                continue
    return [files, contribution, churn]
```

How can I utilize this same code but check churn only if there is changes in code that is only 3 weeks old?

Comment: `git log --stat` will show additions and deletions in a format that is easier to process.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your comment. My main issue is I need to calculate churn only on those files that has been changed less than 21 days old. How can I do so?

Comment: I'm not sure taking it in to pandas is the right solution.  You need an index by file name where you can hold that files last change date.

Comment: How would you do it without pandas? Is it okay if you post your way of solution if you want to?

Answer (score 1):

The only practical way to do this is to iterate through the DataDrame, and because that sucks with pandas, it almost always means you have the wrong data structure.  If you're not doing numerical analysis, and it looks like you aren't, then just keep a simple list of dicts.  Pandas has its shining points, but it's not a universal database.

Here's the rough code you'd need, although I'm glossing over details:

```
# Go through the df row by row.

lastdate = {}
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['filepath'] in lastdate:
        if lastdate[row['filepath']] - row['date'] < timedelta(days=21):
            print( "Last change to", row['filepath'], "was within three weeks" )
    lastdate[row['filepath']] = row['date']
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your way. I got the gist. But in case of particular commit, on what basis should I check the time difference? Should I first list all the files that are changed in that particular commit and see when that same file was previously changed or what? I am totally confused on the date part.

Comment: Well, that's how you have organized your dataframe -- one file per line.  I'm not sure there's any benefit to worrying about commits, but that depends on your spec.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I apologize I could not still solve it. The use case is I need to show the list of commits as activities like github shows a list of commits. From those list of commits, I need to show churn for each individual commit. I could find the churn but not as per proper definition. " Code Churn is when a developer re-writes their own code shortly after it has been checked in (typically within three weeks)." as per pluralsight. (typically within three weeks) is what I could not able to figure out yet.

Comment: Churn, by your definition, is "per file".  I don't know how you will combine the individual "churn" factors for all the files in a commit.  There's your next design challenge.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on designing the solution for this problem? It does not has to be using pandas. I have an idea but I am not sure yet. My idea is find the files changed by that particular commit and then find for each file when it was changed previously(dont know the way though). If its within 21 days, calculate the churn there after.

Comment: If it were me, I'd process the list in reverse order (oldest to newest) and track the last modification date in a dict (`lastdate[filename] = date`).  If a file appears in the last and the new change is less than 21 days from the last one, then that file gets marked as "churn".